# UnityVS visual studio can not open

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityvs

I use UnityVS generate visual studio project, but project file ***.CSharp.csproj could not open.

I find the problem is that ProjectTypeGuids use a unkown type : E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1  , and google also could not tell me what's that.

anyone has the same problem?

The project file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.20506</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{70B74EA9-8515-0DD0-B4E6-E001BFFC1148}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Assembly-CSharp</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETFramework</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Unity Subset v3.5</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <CompilerResponseFile></CompilerResponseFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>Temp\UnityVS_bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN;ENABLE_MICROPHONE;ENABLE_TEXTUREID_MAP;ENABLE_AUDIO_FMOD;UNITY_STANDALONE;ENABLE_MONO;ENABLE_TERRAIN;ENABLE_SUBSTANCE;ENABLE_GENERICS;ENABLE_MOVIES;ENABLE_WWW;ENABLE_IMAGEEFFECTS;ENABLE_WEBCAM;RENDER_SOFTWARE_CURSOR;ENABLE_NETWORK;ENABLE_PHYSICS;ENABLE_CACHING;ENABLE_CLOTH;ENABLE_SHADOWS;ENABLE_AUDIO;ENABLE_DUCK_TYPING;ENABLE_SINGLE_INSTANCE_BUILD_SETTING;UNITY_4_2_2;UNITY_4_2;ENABLE_PROFILER;UNITY_EDITOR;UNITY_EDITOR_WIN;UNITY_TEAM_LICENSE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>Temp\UnityVS_bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN;ENABLE_MICROPHONE;ENABLE_TEXTUREID_MAP;ENABLE_AUDIO_FMOD;UNITY_STANDALONE;ENABLE_MONO;ENABLE_TERRAIN;ENABLE_SUBSTANCE;ENABLE_GENERICS;ENABLE_MOVIES;ENABLE_WWW;ENABLE_IMAGEEFFECTS;ENABLE_WEBCAM;RENDER_SOFTWARE_CURSOR;ENABLE_NETWORK;ENABLE_PHYSICS;ENABLE_CACHING;ENABLE_CLOTH;ENABLE_SHADOWS;ENABLE_AUDIO;ENABLE_DUCK_TYPING;ENABLE_SINGLE_INSTANCE_BUILD_SETTING;UNITY_4_2_2;UNITY_4_2;ENABLE_PROFILER;UNITY_EDITOR;UNITY_EDITOR_WIN;UNITY_TEAM_LICENSE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.XML" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Boo.Lang" />
    <Reference Include="UnityScript.Lang" />
    <Reference Include="UnityEngine">
      <HintPath>Library\UnityAssemblies\UnityEngine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UnityEditor">
      <HintPath>Library\UnityAssemblies\UnityEditor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFCamera.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFCxForm.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFDisplayInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFDisplayMatrix.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFEvents.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFGamepad.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFInitParams.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFKey.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFLifecycleEvent.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFManager_Imports.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFMovie.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFMovie_Imports.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFRTT.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFSentinal.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFValue.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\scaleform\SFValue_Imports.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Assets\Scripts\UI\MyCamera.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\SyntaxTree\UnityVS\2012\UnityVS.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please do not misuse it.

Comment: What version of UnityVS, Unity3D and MS Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I have try UnityVS 1.2.2  and 1.8, Unity3D 4.2.2  and 4.3 , Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, and none of them are useful.

Comment: the project file is generated by UnityVS, and visual studio could not recognize it.

Answer (score 9):

This typically happens in three different scenarios:

- The user is using a trial version of Visual Studio. Currently UnityVS requires a full Visual studio.
- The installation failed to recreate the Visual Studio extension cache. We saw this happen if there was a stray devenv.exe process. Make sure no devenv.exe process is running, and re-install UnityVS.
- The user has an old cracked version of UnityVS installed in the GAC which conflicts with the current UnityVS.

There's also the case where you haven't installed the .NET 3.5 framework which is required by Unity (Unity's class library is a subprofile of .NET 3.5), but the error message is usually explicit about this.

Comment: Had to reinstall 3 times but then it worked. -.- One time I was running Visual Studio and it offered to close it for me and reopen it, but that screwed things up.

Comment: the tip for installing .net 3.5 from https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=21 is a general applicable hint for Windows 10 Users ;)

Answer (score 7):

I've fixed this issue by removing and installing UnityVS again. The "Repair" function of UnityVS installer has not changed anything, so I needed to uninstall it completely first.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually remove these tags inside proj file.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids></ProjectTypeGuids>
```

The error message should be gone, but you're not able to use the debug function. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: I upvoted this because it fixed the immediate problem, but this is more of a dirty patch than a definitive fix. I suggest anybody with this problem to install VS Community instead of Express, and then uninstall and reinstall UnityVS. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked for me was to forcibly re-import the Visual Studio Tools for Unity asset in my Unity project (by importing a custom package and navigating to the package in the Program Files folder).

I think the older version of the tool was not being replaced in my Unity projects even when I re-installed the tool and added it in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this took me about a day to solve. For my use case:

- I had a Unity 2021.1.x project. I upgraded to 2021.2.x (actually a completely clean install - I reinstalled windows) and visual studio 2022 17.2 preview.
- I deleted all of the .sln and .csproj files from the root (backing them up, of course).
- I regenerated all of the csproj files (and sln). Compilation in Unity worked fine, but opening any file in VS yielded the error:

> ```
> There is a missing project subtype.
> Subtype: '{E097FAD1-6243-4DAD-9C02-E9B9EFC3FFC1}' is unsupported by this installation.
> ```

- Forcefully uninstalling and reinstalling the workload "Game development with Unity" from the visual studio installer worked, and subsequent regeneration of the project and solution files yielded no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Full remove of UnityVS and reinstall helped me with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Also removed and reimported UnityVS package in Unity project, not sure if this is required.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio". A "repair" would not fix the problem, but uninstalling and reinstalling with no 'devenv.exe processes running, was the solution. I was using Visual Studio 2013 Community, and opened the project via the Unity toolbar (Visual Studio Tools\Open in Visual Studio).

@Jb Evain - Additional thanks to you for pointing me in the right direction on my own similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2010 Professional after I uninstalled another version of Visual Studio I wasn't using (2013 Express).

None of the other solutions worked for me, but after doing a **repair of VS2010** using the installation disk it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Stopped getting this error after just removing the Visual Editing package in Unity's Package Manager. No errors so far.